# Menu Item does not break like but pushes one word over the other when re-sizing window

Tags: html, css, wordpress, list, word-wrap

It's probably something small, but I cannot figure it out. When resizing the browser window, the string in the list items don't break onto a new line. (see image) I tried to add overflow-wrap:normal. But no success.

It's on this page (click hamburger menu in top left corner) http://lofthotel.multisitech.kinsta.cloud/homepage-3/

Thanks for your help!
Jan

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNwUp.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its fixed already on your page? This is often caused in combination with line-height or overflow-wrap

Comment: No it's not fixed ... overflow-wrap is set to normal

Comment: I did follow up on your suggestions though and setting line-height to above zero solved the problem. Thank you!!!